# How to reset/remove a shortcut?

Tags: shortcut

I have just started using Blender but I feel stupid that I can't find how to reset/remove shortcut added through

[image]

By accident I have added a right mouse to `Remove Doubles` so my right click functionality is gone. Every time I right click Blender tries to remove doubles and I can't seem to be able to reverse to standard behaviour..

I have tried exporting/importing factory settings through user preferences ( Input tab ) but that didn't work.

So can you please point me in the right direction how to reset the shortcuts?

Using Blender 2.69.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can reset the shortcut in the *User Preferences* (Menu / File / User Preferences) <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>U</kbd>

- Select the input tab
- Searching the command
- Click the x right to the shortcut to remove the shortcut.

[image]

Comment: beautiful! I wouldn't find it myself. Thank you very much