# What is the Fn+U equivalent on windows?

Tags: shortcut

Trying to change the shortcut. It's the call menu for the UV Map in edit mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Unwrap](https://www.blender.org/manual/ru/editors/uv_image/uv_editing/unwrapping/mapping_types.html#unwrap) menu in Edit mode is called with just <kbd>U</kbd>, no <kbd>Fn</kbd> should be needed (as a side note <kbd>Fn</kbd> button like many others is OS independant and will work on Windows as well). If you changed the shortcut and would like to recover initial one try [resetting it](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6233/how-to-reset-remove-a-shortcut). Also you might want to rollback unwanted changes to user preferences by [loading factory settings](https://www.blender.org/manual/de/preferences/introduction.html#load-factory-settings) (note that will rollback not only shortcuts but all user preferences).

Answer (score 0):

in the menu, right click --> change shortcut --> put in shortcut. Try seeing if ALT + U is used.