# Why is Shift+D Duplicate creating linked duplicates?

Tags: modeling, objects, edit-mode

So I've been learning Blender for the last week or so and have been having a blast!

I did stumble onto a very frustrating problem though. Whenever I duplicate an object using <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>, it creates a linked duplicate as if I had used the command <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> instead. I first noticed this during a tutorial where the presenter duplicated an object several times and then rotated each one individually. Mine would all rotate together. I thought I might have enabled an option accidentally while following tutorials so I tested this in a brand new scene with just a cube. Sure enough after making a couple of duplicates (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>), any changes made to the original were instantly copied to the duplicates.

I'm not sure if I'm missing something very obvious here, I don't think that is the normal behavior for the <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> function. I'm kind of at a loss. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: See if the shortcut for duplicating wasn't changed, related - http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6233/how-to-reset-remove-a-shortcut. Normally Shift+D creates full copy.

Comment: click on 1 object and press U > unlink object & data and then select that object then make it duplicate shift+d

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So I discovered what the problems was. In the User Preferences > Editing tab, the Mesh option was unchecked under Duplicate Data. After enabling it the <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> duplicate functions normally. I unchecked it again just to make sure that it was indeed what was causing my issue.